# bash replace mime placeholder with multiple line

Tags: bash, sed, mime

I have a template email in MIME and part of the email body is the placeholder `${result}`.

```
  <body>
      <p>${result}</p>
  </body>
```

In the bash script, I have a variable `$RESULT` that store the following table in a string.

```
----------------------------------------------------
           Sydney    Tokyo      London     New York      
product1      100      120           0           70
product2        4       80         210          110
product3      150       50          80           20
----------------------------------------------------
```

I've got couple of more placeholder need to be replaced(just a short string or a word), so I have used the following `sed` command, however it returns an error:

```
sed -e "s/\${subject}/$1/" \
    -e "s/\${client}/$NAME/" \
    -e "s/\${result}/$RESULT/" temp-email > client-email
```

Error:

```
sed: -e expression #3, char 64: unterminated `s' command
```

I know it is something to do with the `\n`, but I am just start learning bash and MIME, not sure how I can replace the placeholder with `$RESULT`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please post expected output in your post too?

Comment: I would like to replace the `${result}` with the table above, the table is already stored in `$RESULT` as string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace newlines by `\n`'s usin parameter expansion

```
RESULT=${RESULT//$'\n'/'\n'}
```

Or use Perl than can handle newlines in replacements:

```
CLIENT=$NAME RESULT=$RESULT SUBJECT=$1 perl -pe '
    s/\${(subject|client|result)}/$ENV{ uc $1 }/g'
```